# I want to push unnamed or dynamically named objects (class instances) to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

Context: "Umo Space" is a javascript game I'm working on [Umo Space](https://github.com/kanethemediocre/umospace) is a javascript game I'm working on, with a class "Umo" (universal moving object) which includes the needed variables and member functions to do stuff with an object moving around in 2d space. Currently the game world has predefined planets and enemy ships, but I'm trying to create randomized systems.  In doing so, I need to fill the "planets" array with a random number of "Umo" instances.  I thought I could just push() an unnamed new "Umo" instance into the array, and it seems that I can when I create the first Umo (the sun basically) in the center of the system before the loop for the randomized planets.  However, inside the loop, I do what seems to be the same thing, and shortly thereafter I get an error when I try to use member functions or assign to member variables of the Umo instance.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setorbit' of undefined
> at System.randomplanets (UmoSpace68.html:567)
> at UmoSpace68.html:591

If I comment out that particular line (which uses a member function of Umo), I instead will get an error for assigning the ".name" or ".parentid" member variables.  I thought maybe I needed to assign the Umo dynamic variable names using an "eval()" rather than pushing it unnamed, but that didn't fix anything (and seems to be an... unfavored practice).  In any case, it seems like the push() failed without generating an error message, inside the loop.

This problem also somehow causes another error downstream, in seemingly unrelated code, un-defining my "ships" array (not a member variable of anything, just an array of predefined "Umo"s).

> UmoSpace68.html:789 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ships'
> before initialization
> at update (UmoSpace68.html:789)

If I comment out the function call "testsystem.randomplanets();" all the problems disappear, and all of the Umo functionality is used elsewhere without issue, so the problem is almost certainly in the randomplanets() member function or at least the "System" class (which is not yet used meaningfully).

Here is the smallest relevant code snippet I could muster:

```
class System{
constructor(index, name){
this.index = index; //integer identifying system 
this.name = name; //name of system for display
this.planets = []; //list of planets (to be generated)
this.ships = []; //list of ships (to be generated)
this.bombs = []; //list of bombs used in system
this.difficulty = 1; //Scales ship generation attributes
}
randomplanets(){
    var numplanets = Math.floor(Math.random()*16+2);//random number of planets, 2-17
    var orbitradius = 0; //randomized in the loop
    var planetsize = 0; //randomized in the loop
    this.planets.push( new Umo(0,0,Math.floor(Math.random()*3000+1000), "orange") ); //make the sun 
    this.planets[0].name = this.name; // Star name is same as system name
    i=0;
    while (i<numplanets-1){
        i=i+1; //planets[0] is already the sun, so we can skip index 0;
        orbitradius = Math.floor( (Math.random()*500)*(Math.random()*500) + 2000); //Minimum radius 2000, 0-500^2 more concentrated in center
        planetsize = Math.floor( Math.random()*1000 + 80); //Even distribution of sizes, 80-1080
        this.planets.push( new Umo(0,0,planetsize, randcolor() ) );//this is where the planet gets added to the array
        this.planets[i].name = randname(4);//random 4 character name
        this.planets[i].setorbit(this.planets[0], orbitradius, Math.random()*6.28, 1);
        this.planets[i].parentid = 0; //establishes star (planet[0] as parent planet
        //this.randommoons(i);
        }
    }
randommoons(index){//index is of planet
    var nummoons = Math.floor(Math.random()*planets[index].s/150 )//Planets < 150 in size have 0 chance of a moon, planet 300 in size has 50% chance of 1 moon, etc.
    var moonsize = 0; //randomized in loop
    var moonorbitr = 0;//randomized in loop
    var moonindex = 0; //set in loop
    i = nummoons;
    while (i>0){
        i=i-1;
        moonsize = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.planets[index].s/3+10);//radius is 10 plus up to 1/3 of parent planet
        moonorbitr = Math.floor(this.planets[index].s*(Math.random()*3+1.5)); //orbit radius is 1.5x parent planet radius + up to 3x parent planet radius
        moonindex = this.planets.length;
        this.planets.push( new Umo(0,0,moonsize, randcolor()) );
        this.planets[moonindex].name = randname(4);
        this.planets[moonindex].parentid = index;
        this.planets[moonindex].setorbit(this.planets[index],moonorbitr,Math.random()*6.28, 1);//orbit direction is 1, not random
        }
    }
}//end of system class////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let testsystem = new System(2,"thetestsystem");
testsystem.randomplanets();
```

Comment: this.planets[i].setorbit = this.planets[0], orbitradius, Math.random()*6.28, 1; try this

Comment: it loocks like you are trying to call a function that does not exist

Comment: Your `i` counter is going backwards, whereas when you `Array.push`, it adds to the beginning of the array. Try changing your loop from a `while` to `for (let i = 0; i< numPlanets - 1; i++)`

Comment: in response to stefan:  setorbit is a member function of the Umo class, not a member variable.  I tried your syntax, and I got the error 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setorbit' of undefined
    at System.randomplanets (UmoSpace68.html:567)
    at UmoSpace68.html:592"

Which makes sense, because there is not a member variable to write to.  If there was, it would need to use array notation to be sensible anyways, no?

Comment: @Sal:  Your solution seems to work, with minor tweaks, but I don't understand why.  My modified version of your for loop was:
for (let i = 1; i< numplanets - 1; i++){
//stuff goes here
}
versus original
var i=0;
while (i<numplanets){
i++;
//stuff
}

Both should start at 1, and increment through numplanets - 1 as I understand them.  What am I missing?

Comment: When you `push` something to an array, it adds it to the next available index starting from index 0. Maybe I missed something in your logic that made the first usable index 1 instead of 0, which seems like the expected behavior. So with that minor discrepancy aside, when you decrement, `i` originally starts at some number, say `10` for example. When you `push` a new element, your array looks like `[<obj1>, <obj2>]`, but you try to access `this.planets[i]`, where `i` is 10. Your array has a length of 2, meaning index `10` is out of bounds, so the value at `this.planets[10]` is `undefined`

Comment: The "sun" is added outside the loop, using the 0 index.  I get that decrementing goes down and incrementing goes up, but I'm incrementing (i = i+1;) and starting at i=0 in the randomplanets function that I'm using.

The randommoons function, and many others in the program, do decrement, but it's not being called or generating an error.

Comment: I think I found the real culprit while writing a random bot ship assignment algo--my randname(number) function had it's own loop, which used i = number; rather than var i=number;, and thus was affecting the i value used here.  Apparently the i in the for loop statement is somehow protected from that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was not in the randomplanets() function after all.  @Sal suggested changing the while loop to a for loop, which DID fix the problem, but more importantly led me to later discover a more fundamental problem while developing random ship generation.  I eventually isolated the problem to the randname(namelength) function, which initiated it's own while loop with:

```
i=namelength;
```

which i changed to

```
var i=namelength;
```

I think that leaving out the "var" caused the randname function to operate on the "i" immediately outside the randname function, inside the randomplanets function (perhaps globally as well).  I think that using a for loop must have protected the "i" used in the for loop from this scope error.

Moral of the story:  Remember to declare your iterator with a "var" each time you use it, especially if you habitually use i,j,k, etc.